Are they sufficient conditions for jointly normal distribution?
Suppose $\theta$, $u_1$, $u_2$ all follow normal distributions. Let $x_1$=$\theta+u_1$ and $x_2$=$\theta+u_2$.
Are the above conditions sufficient to imply that $\theta$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ follow a jointly normal distribution?
If not, how about additionally assuming $\theta$ is uncorrelated with $u_1$ and $\theta$ is uncorrelated with $u_2$?
My intuition is that even the conditions in the first paragraph are already sufficient. But I don't know which theorem I should use to derive it.
Edit: This paper motives this question. Line 16 on page 429 indicates $x_1$=$\theta+u_1$ and $x_2$=$\theta+u_2$. The last lines on page 429 indicates that conditional on $theta$, $u_1$ and $u_2$ follow jointly normal distributions. Line 12 on pagee 430 indicates $\theta$ follows a normal distribution. Line 14 on page 430 indicates $\theta$ is uncorrelated with $u_1$ and $\theta$ is uncorrelated with $u_2$ (because $m_0$ is a constant).
After reading @user6247850's answer, I think this paper is wrong. In @user6247850's example, conditional on $x_1=0$, the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is the original normal distribution; conditional on $x_1\neq0$, the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is a Dirac distribution on $\frac{x_1}{2}$. These results contradict equations (2) and (3) on page 430.
I think in @user6247850's example, $\theta$ and $u$ are not indepedent. Consider $w>0$. $Pr(\theta<w\text{ and } u_1<w)=Pr(-w<\theta<w)+Pr(\theta<-w)/2=\frac{3}{2}\Phi(\omega)-\frac{1}{2}$ but $Pr(\theta<w)Pr(u_1<w)=\Phi^2(w)$.
I was wondering if we strenghthen the condition to $\theta$ being indepedent of $u_1$ and $u_2$, can we reach the conclusion that $\theta$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ follow a jointly normal distribution? If so, is "$\theta$ being indepedent of $u_1$ and $u_2$" also a necessary condition?

Take a look at this answer and recall the definition of a normal random vector. It might be useful for finding a counterexample.

No, this is not true.  Let $\theta \sim N(0,1)$, $Z$ be a random variable independent of $\theta$ with $\mathbb{P}(Z = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Z=-1) = \frac 12$, and $u_1 := Z\theta$.  Then $u_1$ and $\theta$ are both normally distributed and uncorrelated, but $x_1 = \theta + u_1$ is $0$ with probability $\frac 12$, so it cannot be jointly normally distributed with any random variable.

Thank you very much! I edited my question to add some further thoughts. Could you please check it?

@Ypbor It would be better to ask that as a separate question, but yes, if $\theta, u_1,$ and $u_2$ are all independent, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ would be jointly normal.  More generally, if $\theta, u_1,$ and $u_2$ are all jointly normal, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are also jointly normal because a linear combination of jointly normal random variables is jointly normal.
